# Ads are not loading in cypress v10.9.0

Tags: cypress, ads

I am trying to test the ads that appears in the top of the page, I am currently using cypress v10.9.0. When i run the test, i dont get to see the ads loading. It is supposed to be here .

[No ads](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gdLKR.png)

But when i open the same link in normal chrome or new tab in cypress runner I get to see the ads loading

[website with ads in new tab of cypress ui](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PgKFg.png)

have done the following in my config file

```
chromeWebSecurity: false,
    modifyObstructiveCode:false,
```

Comment: Got the same problem using cypress run command (no problem when using cypress open command).

Comment: Hello @john, I still get the issue (mentioned on my previous comment) but it seem to work if I change the browser (for me the problem was on Chrome) to electron.
If you use an ads blocker, be sure it's deactivate too.
If you have any repository to reproduce, feel free to post it here : https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/26879